# Slow LINQ Query on Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I'm using EF 6 with .NET Core. I have written the following query to select some data into a custom object. At the moment the main query returns over 25000 records. Then the filters are applied. This query is running very slow. I'm just trying to find out if I'm doing any mistakes here. Why it could be so slow and is the filtering happening on the memory rather than on the database side?

```
public IQueryable<TicketViewModel> GetTickets(int companyId, string locale, TicketFilterViewModel filters, Guid customerRef, int? take, int currentUser)
        {
            IQueryable<TicketViewModel> tickets = (from to in _context.Ticket
                                                   join co in _context.Company on to.CompanyId equals co.CompanyId
                                                   join con in _context.Contact on to.ContactId equals con.ContactId
                                                   join site in _context.Site on to.SiteId equals site.SiteId
                                                   join country in _context.Country on site.CountryId equals country.CountryId
                                                   join cus in _context.Customer on con.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                                                   join tic_type in _context.TicketType on to.TicketTypeId equals tic_type.TicketTypeId
                                                   join ts in _context.TicketStatus on to.TicketStatusId equals ts.TicketStatusId
                                                   join sb in _context.ServiceBoard on to.ServiceBoardId equals sb.ServiceBoardId into ob1
                                                   from a in ob1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                   join u in _context.User on to.TechnitianId equals u.Id into ob2
                                                   from b in ob2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                   join pr in _context.Priority on to.PriorityId equals pr.PriorityId into ob3
                                                   from c in ob3.DefaultIfEmpty()                                                  
                                                   where to.CompanyId == companyId && (customerRef == Guid.Empty || cus.RefNo == customerRef)
                                                   && to.MergedIntoTicketId == null
                                                   select new TicketViewModel
                                                   {
                                                       CreatedOn = Helpers.Custom.UtcToStandardTime(locale, to.AddedOnUtc).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"),
                                                       CustomerName = cus.CustomerName,
                                                       TicketNumber = to.TicketNumber,
                                                       TicketTitle = to.TicketTitle,
                                                       RefNo = to.RefNo,
                                                       CompanyName = co.CompanyName,
                                                       ContactName = string.Concat(con.FirstName, " ", con.LastName),
                                                       SiteAddress = String.Concat(site.AddressLine1, ", ", site.AddressLine2, ", ", site.Suburb, ", ", site.State, ", ", site.PostCode, ", ", country.Name),
                                                       ServiceBoardName = a.BoardName,
                                                       TechnicianName = string.Concat(b.FirstName, " ", b.LastName),
                                                       PriorityName = c.PriorityName,
                                                       TicketStatus = ts.StatusName, //d.StatusName,
                                                       ServiceBoardId = to.ServiceBoardId,
                                                       TicketStatusId = to.TicketStatusId,
                                                       CustomerId = cus.CustomerId,
                                                       PriorityId = to.PriorityId,
                                                       ContractId = site.ContractId,
                                                       TechnitianId = to.TechnitianId,
                                                       TicketId = to.TicketId,
                                                       StatusCategoryId = ts.CategoryId,//,//d.CategoryId,
                                                       DueOnUtc = to.DueOnUtc,
                                                       DefaultStatusId = ts.DefaultId,//d.DefaultId,
                                                       ClosedOnUtc = to.ClosedOnUtc,
                                                       ResolvedOnUtc = to.ResolvedOnUtc,
                                                       InitialResponseMade = to.InitialResponseMade,
                                                       TicketTypeId = to.TicketTypeId,
                                                       TicketTypeName = tic_type.TicketTypeName

                                                   }).OrderByDescending(o => o.TicketNumber);


            bool isFiltersHit = false;

            if (filters != null)
            {
                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.serviceboard_selectedItems != null && filters.serviceboard_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.ServiceBoardId != null && filters.serviceboard_selectedItems.Select(o => o.serviceBoardId).Contains(x.ServiceBoardId.Value));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.status_selectedItems != null && filters.status_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.TicketStatusId != null && filters.status_selectedItems.Select(o => o.ticketStatusId).Contains(x.TicketStatusId.Value));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.type_selectedItems != null && filters.type_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => filters.type_selectedItems.Select(o => o.ticketTypeId).Contains(x.TicketTypeId));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.technician_selectedItems != null && filters.technician_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.TechnitianId != null && filters.technician_selectedItems.Select(o => o.id).Contains(x.TechnitianId.Value));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.customer_selectedItems != null && filters.customer_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.CustomerId != 0 && filters.customer_selectedItems.Select(o => o.customerId).Contains(x.CustomerId));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.priority_selectedItems != null && filters.priority_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.PriorityId != null && filters.priority_selectedItems.Select(o => o.priorityId).Contains(x.PriorityId.Value));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.contract_selectedItems != null && filters.contract_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.ContractId != null && filters.contract_selectedItems.Select(o => o.contractId).Contains(x.ContractId.Value));

                }

                if (tickets != null && tickets.Count() > 0 && filters.source_selectedItems != null && filters.source_selectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    isFiltersHit = true;

                    tickets = tickets.Where(x => x.SourceId != 0 && filters.source_selectedItems.Select(o => o.item_id).Contains(x.SourceId));

                }

            }


            if (take.HasValue)
                return tickets.Take(take.Value);

            return tickets;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what the generated sql looks like?

Comment: is the translated sql-query or the execution of your code slow?

Comment: This wouldn't improve the query, but using Navigation Properties when possible will make the code easier to read.

Comment: One issue is that you run that query over and over in those `if` statements when you do `Count`.  If you don't have any results then adding more filters isn't going to hurt.

Comment: Neither "tickets != null" nor "tickets.Count() > 0" are needed in the filters section (tickets will never be null, and you don't care if there are any results yet as lazy evaluation will build the actual query when you try to evaluate the completed query plus filters together). Try feeding the resulting query string into the DB query optimiser to find if you are missing required indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compose the query based on your conditions from the filters, you will see a big improvement. Meaning, create a base query ( base and minimum conditions ) and then add the conditions one by one, depending on what your filters are. Execute the query after all filters are checked.

P.S: you don't really need to call `tickets.Count()` on every filter. Do it once, in the beginning.

Comment: I'm not sure they need to call `Count` at all.  Adding more filters to a query that returns no results will still just produce no results.

Comment: Thanks, It was actually the count slowing down the query. I removed it and now it's fairly fast. Thanks

Comment: The thing is, you don't even need the `Count` as you don't actually use it anywhere. You can try `Any()` instead.